# How do I build an older version of V8?

Tags: android, cross-compiling, v8, embedded-v8, depottools

I tried to build an older version of V8 for android. Target version is 6.5
https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-65

Building guide is here: https://v8.dev/docs/build

```
git clone https://github.com/v8/v8
cd v8

git checkout 6.5-lkgr

build/install-build-deps-android.sh

echo "target_os = ['android']" >> ../.gclient && gclient sync
```

After the above steps, I see below settings in v8/src/include/v8-version.h

```
define V8_MAJOR_VERSION 7
define V8_MINOR_VERSION 3
define V8_BUILD_NUMBER 0
define V8_PATCH_LEVEL 0
```

This is strange to me. Because [this guide](https://medium.com/@hyperandroid/compile-v8-for-arm-7-df45372f9d4e) does the same steps but it succeeded.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The guide you linked to also uses `fetch v8` instead of manually cloning from GitHub, which performs important initialization ;-)

If you insist on not following the recommended instructions, you'll have to set up your `.gclient` manually. For this specific issue, I guess it lacks `"managed": False,`. But I'd really recommend to follow the given instructions to avoid such issues.

Comment: cloning url is not recommended :D